# enabling https in eclipse tomcat server not allowing calls to port 8080

Tags: java, eclipse, https

I set up ssl certification in eclipse tomcat. After setting up 8443 port work fine but now when i try to access
http://localhost:8080/myapp/page.html
it does not work.

without ssl my app was working fine i need to run the code in https enabled environment but code should work with 8080 port.

These two urls should work in parallel

https://localhost:8443/readapp/multiHostDeviceInfo.html?host=xyz&param=device&intl=1

Key created using this command

```
keytool -genkey -alias localhost -keyalg RSA -keystore /Users/name/Documents/keystore.keystore
```

i put this in my server.xml

```
 <Connector port="8443"  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
    enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
    acceptCount="100" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLSv1"
    keystoreFile="/Users/myName/Documents/keystore.keystore"
    keystorePass="password" />
```

Error i am getting while opening project

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:422)
```

I added it to java certificates using this command

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias <AliasName> -file   <certificate> -keystore <KeystoreFile> -storepass <Password>
```

After restarting tomcat i got following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.security.KeyStoreException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys
```

This is my keystore file

```
beat, 7 Mar, 2018, trustedCertEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): xyz
localhost, 7 Mar, 2018, PrivateKeyEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): xyz
```

I removed entry from this beat, 7 Mar, 2018, trustedCertEntry

Then i came back to handshake issue.

Thanks

Comment: Is that `https://localhost:8080/readapp/multiHostDeviceInfo.html?host=xyz&param=device&intl=1` in the question a typo in the port number?

Comment: Changed to 8443

Comment: Your keystore file looks wrong.  It should be a private key which will not present as clear text.

Comment: I created key using command      keytool -genkey -alias localhost -keyalg RSA -keystore /Users/name/Documents/keystore.keystore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the tomcat instructions [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) and it is all working well for me (using alias localhost and password = password)

I can see you are using Windows, so make sure that the path to the keystore file is prefixed with the drive e.g. C:/Users/myName/Documents/keystore.keystore

If that doesn't work I suggest to recreate the .keystore file.  You should be prompted with a series of questions such as for your password, your first and last name, org unit, city etc.  The .keystore file if created succesfully should not be in clear text.

Also for a self signed certificate (I assume this is for your local desktop and not production), you don't need to run the keytool -import command.  Just point your server.xml file to the generated .keystore file like you are already doing.